Regularity of Poisson's Equation with Lipschitz source term
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth domain (i.e., smooth boundary) and consider the following Dirichlet problem:
\begin{align}
\Delta u &= f \ \text{ in } \Omega\\
u &= 0  \text{ on  } \partial \Omega\\
\end{align}
Using Kellogg's theorem and Schauder estimates, if $f \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$  for  $0< \alpha <1$, then we pretty much have complete regularity theory that says $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$.
I'm particularly interested in the case when $\alpha =0$ and $\alpha =1$ especially. Specifically, for the case when $\alpha =1$, are there any assumptions on the domain that I need to claim that $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$?
Theorem 7 (c) in this note says if $f$ is Lipschitz on a compactly supported domain, then $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$: https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec11.pdf
But I'm not quite sure what the justification for this assumption is.
The best reasoning I have for this is:

Compactly supported Lipschitz functions are dense in $L^p$, thus we can replace  $f \in \text{Lip}(\Omega)$ with $f \in L^p(\Omega)$
Use the Sobolev regularity and Morrey's embedding theorem as shown in this post (Elliptic regularity estimate for Possion with bounded forcing term)
to get $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$ as desired.

